# Object reference not set to an instance of an object for RaygunClient

Tags: c#, xunit.net, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a controller in my asp.net core 2.1 project which has `IOptions<RaygunSettings>` as constructor parameter.

Dependency Injection is added in Startup.cs as shown below.

```
services.AddRaygun(Configuration);
```

Everything works fine when you run the web application. But when It didn't work for xunit project.

**SampleController.cs**

```
private readonly RaygunClient raygunClient;
public SampleController(IOptions<RaygunSettings> settings)
{
    _settings = settings;
    raygunClient = new RaygunClient(_settings.Value);
}

private Mock<IOptions<RaygunSettings>> _settings;
```

**SampleControllerTest.cs**

```
public SampleControllerTest()
{
    //Arrange
    _settings = new Mock<IOptions<RaygunSettings>>();
     _controller = new SampleController(_settings.Object);
}
```

Above code explains how my SampleController and SampleControllerTest constructor looks like.

When I try to run the xunit test at the raygunclient instantiation time I'm getting

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

How to fix this issue in xunit test project for asp.net core 2.1

Comment: The question I have to ask is: what's null?

Comment: Raygunsettings value is null

Comment: Do you mean `_settings.Value`? or `settings`? If you mean `_settings.Value`, it's because you didn't mock it, I believe. All your `SampleControllerTest` code does it create a mock of `IOptions<RaygunSettings>` without mocking any of the methods/properties.

Comment: yes @John _settings.Value is null. Moreover I don't know how to pass dependency injection to controller from controllerTest since I don't have a startup.cs in my xunit test project

Comment: You created a dummy/mocked object `_settings`. You should also implement what `_settings.Value` should return.

Comment: _settings.Value returns null @ilian-pinzon

Comment: It returns null because *you* have to supply its value. You created `_settings` (via the mock), you should also implement what `_settings.Value` returns. I don't mean to be rude but is this your first time using mocks? I think you are using Moq? If so, it will be helpful to understand how mocking and Moq works first. Look at how to mock [properties](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#properties) especially. You need to do something like `_settings.Setup(s=> s.Value).Returns(/* your object here */);`

Comment: @ilian-pinzon yes it is my first time using mocks. ya sure will check documentation first.